# Spark - Iterating through all rows in dataframe comparing multiple columns for each row against another

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
| match_id | player_id | team | win |
|    0     |      1    |   A  |  A  |
|    0     |      2    |   A  |  A  |
|    0     |      3    |   B  |  A  |
|    0     |      4    |   B  |  A  |
|    1     |      1    |   A  |  B  |
|    1     |      4    |   A  |  B  |
|    1     |      8    |   B  |  B  |
|    1     |      9    |   B  |  B  |
|    2     |      8    |   A  |  A  |
|    2     |      4    |   A  |  A  |
|    2     |      3    |   B  |  A  |
|    2     |      2    |   B  |  A  |
```

I have a dataframe that looks like above.

I need to to create a map (key,value) pair such that for every

`(k=>(player_id_1, player_id_2), v=> 1 )`, if player_id_1 wins against player_id_2 in a match

and

`(k=>(player_id_1, player_id_2), v=> 0 )`, if player_id_1 loses against player_id_2 in a match

I will have to thus iterate through the entire data frame comparing each player id to another based upon the other 3 columns.

I am planning to achieve this as follows.

1. Group by match_id
2. In each group for a player_id check against other player_id's the following

   a. If match_id is same and team is different
   Then

   ```
        if team =  win
          (k=>(player_id_1, player_id_2), v=> 0 )
        else team != win
          (k=>(player_id_1, player_id_2), v=> 1 )
   ```

For example, after partitioning by matches consider match 1.
player_id 1 needs to be compared to player_id 2,3 and 4.
While iterating, record for player_id 2 will be skipped as the team is same
for player_id 3 as team is different the team & win will be compared.
As player_id 1 was in team A and player_id 3 was in team B and team A won the key-value formed would be

```
((1,3),1)
```

I have a fair idea of how to achieve this in imperative programming but I am really new to scala and functional programming and can't get a clue as to how while iterating through every row for a field create a (key,value) pair by having checks on other fields.

I tried my best to explain the problem. Please do let me know if any part of my question is unclear. I would be happy to explain the same. Thank you.

P.S: I am using Spark 1.6

Comment: The case that you took to generate `((1,3),1)` would also generate `((2,4),1)` or do you just want to skip the second player ids altogether?

Comment: this is just an inner or self join.

Comment: @philantrovert Yes I would need the ((2,4),1) too.  This was to be done for all player_ids.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram Thank you . I used rogue-one 's solution using inner joins and conditions mentioned and had it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved using the DataFrame API as shown below..

**Dataframe API version**:

```
val df = Seq((0,1,"A","A"),(0,2,"A","A"),(0,3,"B","A"),(0,4,"B","A"),(1,1,"A","B"),(1,4,"A","B"),(1,8,"B","B"),(1,9,"B","B"),(2,8,"A","A"),(2,4,"A","A"),(2,3,"B","A"),(2,2,"B","A")
).toDF("match_id", "player_id", "team", "win")

val result = df.alias("left")
       .join(df.alias("right"), $"left.match_id" === $"right.match_id" && not($"right.team" === $"left.team"))
       .select($"left.player_id", $"right.player_id", when($"left.team" === $"left.win", 1).otherwise(0).alias("flag"))

scala> result.collect().map(x => (x.getInt(0),x.getInt(1)) -> x.getInt(2)).toMap
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[(Int, Int),Int] = Map((1,8) -> 0, (3,4) -> 0, (3,1) -> 0, (9,1) -> 1, (4,1) -> 0, (8,1) -> 1, (2,8) -> 0, (8,3) -> 1, (1,9) -> 0, (1,4) -> 1, (8,2) -> 1, (4,9) -> 0, (3,2) -> 0, (1,3) -> 1, (4,8) -> 0, (4,2) -> 1, (2,4) -> 1, (8,4) -> 1, (2,3) -> 1, (4,3) -> 1, (9,4) -> 1, (3,8) -> 0)
```

**SPARK SQL version**:

```
df.registerTempTable("data_table")

val result = sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT DISTINCT t0.player_id, t1.player_id, CASE WHEN t0.team == t0.win THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag FROM data_table t0
INNER JOIN data_table t1
ON t0.match_id = t1.match_id
AND t0.team != t1.team
""")
```

Comment: Thank you @rogue-one  for both the solutions. Maybe I was thinking in a way too complicated manner and you made the solutions look so cleaner and easier. :)